# select rows between two values in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is a common question I saw in many places, but don't know yet it possible or not. I'm trying to select rows between 2 and 5 in following way using oracle sql developer tool.

As of result this query, this should select 3rd and 4th query according to below query

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE ROWNUM > 2 AND ROWNUM < 5
```

but it's not selecting the 3rd and 4th rows,

Then I tried the following query

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE RN BETWEEN 2 AND 5
```

This also syntactically and progrmatically correct, but not selecting the exact columns.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` rows get selected in an arbitrary order. So asking for the 3rd or 4th row doesn't make sense.

Comment: Not selecting the exact *columns*? Did you mean "not selecting the exact **rows**"?

Comment: @BobJarvis yes thats it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit of analytics.

Salaries in the EMP table, sorted by $$$, look like this:

```
SQL> select ename, sal
  2  from emp
  3  order by sal;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
SMITH             800
JAMES             950   2   you want to return James ...
WARD             1250   3
MARTIN           1250   4
MILLER           1300   5   ... to Miller
TURNER           1500
ALLEN            1600
CLARK            2450
BLAKE            2850
JONES            2975
FORD             3000
KING             5000

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

If you do it as follows, you'd get what you wanted:

```
SQL> select ename, sal, rn
  2  from (select ename, sal, row_number() over (order by sal) rn
  3        from emp
  4       )
  5  where rn between 2 and 5;

ENAME             SAL         RN
---------- ---------- ----------
JAMES             950          2
WARD             1250          3
MARTIN           1250          4
MILLER           1300          5

SQL>
```

However, as you can see, Ward and Martin earn the same $1250. So, should we count them as having the same salary and include Turner into the list, or not? Yet two another analytic functions might help you decide: `RANK` and `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SQL> select ename, sal,
  2    row_number() over (order by sal) rn,
  3    rank() over (order by sal) rnk,
  4    dense_rank() over (order by sal) drnk
  5  from emp
  6  order by sal;

ENAME             SAL         RN        RNK       DRNK
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
SMITH             800          1          1          1
JAMES             950          2          2          2   2nd isn't questionable, but ...
WARD             1250          3          3          3
MARTIN           1250          4          3          3
MILLER           1300          5          5          4   ... which one is 5th? Miller (RN and RNK), ...
TURNER           1500          6          6          5   ... or Turner (DRNK column)?
ALLEN            1600          7          7          6
CLARK            2450          8          8          7
BLAKE            2850          9          9          8
JONES            2975         10         10          9
FORD             3000         11         11         10
KING             5000         12         12         11

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

To be fair, `DENSE_RANK` is probably the best option in such cases:

```
SQL> select ename, sal, drnk
  2  from (select ename, sal, dense_rank() over (order by sal) drnk
  3        from emp
  4       )
  5  where drnk between 2 and 5;

ENAME             SAL       DRNK
---------- ---------- ----------
JAMES             950          2
WARD             1250          3
MARTIN           1250          3
MILLER           1300          4
TURNER           1500          5

SQL>
```

Now you have several options; pick the one that suits you best.

Comment: `row_number() over (order by sal) rn` and `between 2 and 5` worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, ROWNUM as rn
      FROM MyTable t
     ) t
WHERE rn > 2 AND rn < 5;
```

Note that tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a first or second row.  You should have an `ORDER BY` clause to specify the ordering.

The reason that your version doesn't work is that `rownum` starts at 1 when the first row is put into the result set.  If no row is put in, the value never increments.  So, it never hits 2 or 3.

I should also note that `between` in SQL is inclusive.  So `>=` and `<=` are more appropriate.

EDIT:

I should note that Oracle 12+ supports `FETCH`/`OFFSET`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
offset 2                  -- start on the third row
fetch first 2 rows only   -- fetch two rows in total
```

An `order by` is still recommended in this case.

Comment: I would add to your edit:  The observation about *unordered* sets is a logical thing, unrelated to Oracle version. Even with the `FETCH/OFFSET` syntax, the OP should have an `ORDER BY` clause to specify the ordering.

Comment: thanks for the advice @mathguy , but I tried many queries in SO, didn't work out any of them, so just thought that because of Oracle versions, that's why decided to make a question

Comment: @gordonlinoff when it comes to join many tables how to specifiy "t", since I need to simplyfy the question, I make this way. my actual query remains lot of joins